# Deploying cakePHP project

Tags: cakephp, deployment, cakephp-2.0

How to configure the value of:

CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH 
assuming that my hosting domain is www.example.com
I have made it like:

> if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
>           define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'usr' . DS . 'lib');
>       }

but it's not working and gives me error of:

Warning: include(/usr/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: the domain name is not relevant to your question - where the file `Cake/bootstrap.php` is - is relevant to your question. Ordinarily you don't need to modify this constant at all.

Comment: Cake folder path is in app/lib/Cake and the Cake_core_include_path is configured to be 
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'xampp');

I uploaded it online so I think this Cake_CORE_INCULDE_PATH should be edited.

Comment: since you aren't deploying to xampp - just revert your changes and use [the index file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4/app/webroot/index.php) as it comes from Cake.

Comment: I copied pasted it and it gives me the same error:
Warning: include(Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

And also I want to know if I need to change the path of the core cake folder to anywhere else (I put it in app/lib) .. thank u

Comment: if you have not changed the directory layout - you don't need to change this constant. If you _have_ changed the directory layout (clarify) - you need to change it to point at the folder containing Cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AD7six suggests, you shouldn't need to modify this constant. You need to make sure that the `lib` directory is deployed along with your `app` directory. If you would like to relocate the `lib` directory to somewhere else if you're going to have multiple applications, you need to add the path to the `include_path` in your `php.ini` file (see [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#multiple-cakephp-applications-using-the-same-core)).

In theory you should be able to deploy your application in its entirety straight to your web server and just point your domain mapping to the `index.php` in the root of the CakePHP directory (where `app` and `lib` sit).

Comment: Not accurate. You _may_ modify this constant to point at where Cake is on the server, and it's one of the [documented](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html) ways to install cake. Editing the php.ini file is one way to make it work - it's not the only way (and without root access - i.e. on a shared host - it's not possible to do this).

Comment: You're right @AD7six, I've just found it easier to modify the `include_path` and I feel that I'm not messing with Cake's core. My experience with shared hosting is that you can create a `php.ini` in your web root to override any configuration directives you need to set within the limits of your host's resources.